# Can VMWare Workstation 7.x and Sun VirtualBox 3.1.x co-exist on the same Windows 7 64bit Host together?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, virtualbox, vmware-workstation

Will installing Sun Virtual Box bash or interfere with my VMWare installtion?

I don't need to run VMs from both Virtual-Machine software packages at the same time but I do need to run some older Virtual-Machines from Sun-Virtualbox on the same 64-bit Windows 7 host until I can migrate those VMs to VMWare.

Before switching from Linux host to Windows host, I ensured to export the VirtualBox VM to an OVF "appliance" with intentions of importing into VMWare Workstation 7. But VMWare gives me an error stating it can't import it.

#### Background info

My old workstation host: 32-bit Ubuntu 9.04 running Sun Virtual Box 3.x hosting Windows-XP VM Guest for Windows Software app development (VS2008, etc)

#### Needs

I need to get my original Sun-VBox Windows-XP Guest running on my new Windows 7 Workstation either imported into VMWare or running on the Windows version of Sun-Virtual box (I have the VM-Guest Backed up and copied to the new computer data drive.

**New workstation host:** 64bit Windows 7 running VMWare Workstation 7 to host 32bit Ubuntu 9.10 for linux project work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I currently run both VMWare Workstation 7 and VirtualBox (3.1.6 ISTR) on the same Windows 7 64 bit host.  They co-exist without problems.

Answer (score 0):

With respect to problems importing the appliance into VMWare, I'm about to do the same. During my research, I came across the following page, which might help here: http://blogs.techrepublic.com/window-on-windows/?p=2997. Didn't try it yet, though.